# how can i access a variable globally in react js

Tags: reactjs

here is the code:

```
export const OutputContainer = () => {
const container = document.getElementById("output-elements");
return <div id="output-elements"></div>;
};

export const AppendBtn = () => {
const btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = "Click Me";
container.appendChild(btn);
};
```

how should I access container variable globally.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `getElementById` in React to begin with, and certainly not `document.createElement()`.

If you want to append buttons to a container element, you render them in that component, like so:

```js
function OutputContainer() {
  const [nButtons, setNButtons] = React.useState(0);
  
  return (
    <div id="output-elements">
      <button onClick={() => setNButtons(n => n + 1)}>More buttons!</button>
      {Array(nButtons).fill(null).map((_, i) => <button key={i}>Button {i + 1}</button>)}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<OutputContainer />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```